# "assignment to undeclared variable" when using "for (i=0; ..)"

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm trying to get list of all input fields in a HTML form, but I get following error(in Firebug):

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable i
for (i=0 ; i<inputs.length; i++)
```

I don't understant how is "i" undeclared because that is that first part of "for" does.
This is my formula

```
 function listinputs() 
    {
       var form = document.getElementById("wholeform");
       var inputs = form.childNodes;
       for (i=0 ; i<inputs.length; i++)
       {
          var string=string + inputs[i].nodeName + "<br>";
          var here = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
          here.innerHTML(string);
       }
}
```

Comment: for(var i = 0; ... you need to declare it with var

Comment: `var here = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); here.innerHTML(string);` should be outside your loop, by the way.

Comment: @PHPglue: Yeah, outside the loop and the list returned by `getElementsByTagName` doesn't have an `innerHTML` property...

Comment: I see that now. Yes that would be an Array, that you would have to run another loop on.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
```

You need to declare it with `var`

As T.J said in his answer, since you're using strict mode, an  implicit global is not made. That's why an error is thrown.

Comment: ow yeah I'm not sure why did I miss that. Probabliy due to 3w school example " for (i=0; i<c.length; i++) "

Comment: Yet another reason why w3schools should not be used.

Comment: If it "needs" `var`, then why does `for (q=0;q<10;q++) {q}` Work Here?

Comment: @RUJordan And **that** is the secret! See T.J.'s answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. `strict mode` == no globals == error.

Comment: @RUJordan: It would work only in loose mode, because assigning to an unknown symbol creates an implicit global variable. The OP is using strict mode, where that's quite rightly been made an error.

Comment: @RUJordan: You can still have globals in strict mode, you just have to do them on purpose. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the lesson gents, updated my answer. @T.J.Crowder +1 becuase you obviously knew this before me :D

Answer (score 16):

It's not saying `i` is *unassigned*, it's saying it's *undeclared*. The code never declares an `i` variable, but then tries to assign a value to it (in the initialization part of the `for` loop). Apparently you're using strict mode (good!), and so the engine is giving you an error rather than creating an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Declare `i` using `var` in the function, e.g.:

```
function listinputs() 
{
    var form = document.getElementById("wholeform");
    var inputs = form.childNodes;
    var i; // <=================================== Here
    for (i=0 ; i<inputs.length; i++)
    {
        string=string + inputs[i].nodeName + "<br>";
        here = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        here.innerHTML(string);
    }
}
```

---

Side note: In ES6, when it arrives, if you want you can use `let` and scope `i` to the `for` statement only. But for now, use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR Message

> ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable "x" (Firefox)
>   ReferenceError: "x" is not defined (Chrome)
>  ReferenceError:
>   Variable undefined in strict mode (Edge)

**Invalid cases**
In this case, the variable "**bar**" is an undeclared variable.

```
function foo() { 
  'use strict'; 
  bar = true; 
} 
foo(); // ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable bar
```

**Valid cases**
To make "**bar**" a declared variable, you can add the var keyword in front of it.

```
function foo() {
  'use strict';
  var bar = true;
}
foo();
```

Comment: What if you want bar to be available in the global scope? Then var wouldn't work.