# Trying to understand JS loops

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with understanding JS loops.
I found an online tutorial for a button changing random colors for a div id="container". However, it turns out that the random colors are frequently repeated after a click. I want to change the code and loop through the array colors one by one and change the color of the div#container after each click. This is my code:

```
let colors = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "brown", "orange"];
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let selectColor = colors[i];
  }

  container.style.backgroundColor = selectColor;
});
```

I get the error: assignment to undeclared variable i. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; ...`; you're never declaring `i`  (or `let` instead of `var`). There's other issues, but to address the "assignment to undeclared variable `i`", you need a variable keyword in your `for()` loop declaration.

Comment: Put „let“ in for (let i = ..) like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793924/how-does-let-in-for-loop-work

Comment: @TomDev you've edited your question and now the code has a significant difference from its original version. Are you sure you're still getting the same error? The code still won't produce the result you want, but I'm guessing the error isn't happening any more.

Comment: @jnpdx it's not THAT different when I look at the revisions. And the change wouldn't even matter, since in both the previous and the current version, `selectColor` is going to throw a ReferenceError when used outside the block it's declared. Even then, OP gets an error before that line.

Comment: ["assignment to undeclared variable" when using "for (i=0; ..)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22850380)

Comment: I don't think you need a loop. You just need to get a random number that uses the length of the array, that holds the colors, to select one at random when your code executes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @VLAZ true that it wasn't the only scope error, but it would effect the way the question was framed on the last line "I get the error: assignment to undeclared variable i."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping through all the colors in the array at once, and then only use the last one to set the backgroundcolor.

You should only increment by one and then set the color

```
let colors = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "brown", "orange"];
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let i = 0;
let container = document.getElementById("container");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  i++;
  if(i >= colors.length) i = 0;
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variable i on line 6, so instead of

```
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let selectColor = colors[i];
  }
```

you would have

```
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let selectColor = colors[i];
  }
```

Comment: True, but what is the point of the loop at all?

Comment: There is no point, but the question asked about the error message and JS loops so I provided the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you missed declaring "i" in the for loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let selectColor = colors[i];
}
```

Comment: This has already been added as an answer and a comment; you don't need to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Kokodoko's answer: you don't need a loop because all you need to do is cycle through the array indexes one-by-one when the button is clicked, not all the colours at once.

Here's a slightly different approach which doesn't rely on the array index being a global variable. Instead it returns a function (closure) to the listener that, when called, changes from one colour to another.

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'brown', 'orange'];

const container = document.getElementById('container');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// We call the function which returns a new function
// which is what the button calls
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// Initially set `index` to 0
function handleClick(index = 0) {

  // This is the function the listener will call
  return function() {

    // Set the BG colour to the new index
    // if the index hasn't reached the end of the array
    // otherwise set it to zero, and start again.
    if (index < colors.length - 1) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++];
    } else {
      index = 0;
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px, height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div id="container">Container</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy but your approach is too advanced for me for the time being. I'm still a beginner. I'll figure it out some day. :) Need to learn the basics first.

Comment: @TomDev, I've added some additional comments to the answer. It's ok if you don't understand it if you're a new coder, but [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) are a very versatile method of programming.

Comment: One can meet great guys on this website. Thanks a lot again. I don't understand that"false" in the event listener. Why did you use it?

Comment: No worries. It's the [`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) option. I tend to always include it. @TomDev. Good luck with the coding.